# check an exception to call a C structure from go

Tags: go

I have a structure in C and I called that structure in my go program. If that structure throws any error it terminates my go program like below

```
orderbook.h
-------------
#ifndef _ORDERBOOK_H
#define _ORDERBOOK_H

typedef struct order order;
struct order {
        
        int tradeid;
        int side;
        int symbol;
        double amount;
        double price;
};

orderbook.c
--------------
include "orderbook.h"
order* order_place(char *side,double amount,double price,char symbol[19])
{
struct order *tradeorder= calloc(1000000,sizeof(struct order));//Initlize the structure


//My internal code which place an order 
clob_ord_t o=unxs_order(c, (clob_ord_t){CLOB_TYPE_LMT,parsed_side, amount, .lmt =price, .usr = (uintptr_t)out},NANPX);

if (o.qty.dis + o.qty.hid > 0.dd) {
    /* put remainder of order into book */
   i = clob_add(c, o);
   //printf("orderid..%lu\n", i.usr);
  printf("orderid..%s\n", i.usr);
  insertMap(hashTable, i.usr, i);
//  printMap(hashTable);
 flag=true;
 tradeorder[0].orderstatus=1;
 tradeorder[0].orderid=offerid;
 tradeorder[0].side=sid;
 tradeorder[0].symbol=atoi(symbol);
 tradeorder[0].amount=(double)o.qty.dis;
 tradeorder[0].price=price;

}
return tradeorder; //return the structure
}

main.go
---------
o:=C.order_place(C.CString("ASK"),C.double(12.0),C.double(1.0),C.CString("1")) //this line may get an exception If some wrong parameter to pass otherwise returns correct value
```

If I put correct parameter to order_pace function from go  there is no issue, If I pass some incorrect parameter then In get an exception an it terminates the go server. Now I need to handle that exception so that my server remain running irrespective  of an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can't catch the fatal fault, and it isn't safe to continue after your C code throws a fault (unlike Go). The running program is in an undefined potentially dangerous state. The safest thing to do is shutdown the program and/or let it crash.

You must check for errors within C.order_place and return an error on failure. Eg, return NULL.

A few other recommendations:

- Allocate `struct order` via Go to rely on the garbage collector to simplify memory management.

```golang
var order C.struct_order
C.order_place(&order, side, ...)
```

- Always free strings allocated via `C.CString` once they are no longer needed.

```golang
cstr := C.CString("test")
C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cstr))
```

- Depending on your platform, you can simplify debugging with improved stack traces by importing cgosymbolizer. This adds support for C stack traces.

```golang
import _ "github.com/ianlancetaylor/cgosymbolizer"
```

- You probably should use `char *symbol` instead of `char symbol[19]` in your example since `C.CString` returns a pointer to an arbitrarily long C string, not a pointer to an array of 19 chars.